# Does website registration location affect google searches?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

Let's say I register a .com domain name from a physical address somewhere in Europe. Would that affect the way google lists my website for people in the US, as opposed to if I register from a US physical address?

In general, would the physical address of registration have any impact on internet visibility for my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all, .com is a generic top level domain with NO geographic preference by default

References:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1347922?hl=en
http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db

By the way, the second page gives you the real full list of all country code tlds and generic tlds. Look at the "type" column.

Comment: Merci pour les links :) Would you mind taking a look at this question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/87592/what-are-the-potential-disadvantages-to-registering-a-website-in-someone-elses

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of physical address of registration being a factor in search results, however if you own a `.com` domain you can specify to Google which country your content is intended for through the google webmasters control panel.
That will have an effect on how content is displayed to users in certain countries